# Poedit open a reference with an editor

Tags: php, translation, poedit

I'm using Poedit to translate an application. The Poedit gives the reference to the source text, so I have to open the source find the line, etc. etc. I would be really useful if I could go directly from poedit reference to my editor, let's say Aptana or Notepad++. There's a way to setup Poedit for that purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to http://poedit.net/support.php and follow the link to the bugtracker, you can find  https://www.poedit.net/trac/ticket/520

You can also download beta version of Poedit 1.6 (where that commit is already included) from https://www.poedit.net/download.php

Comment: @Václav Slavík the ticket is gone currently had the same problem with Version 1.8.8